# ¿Algoritmo de búsqueda e inserción para este formato?

Tags: array, algoritmos, búsquedas

pongamos que tengo un array bidimensional de este estilo. Este representa **una plantilla** de excel o de lo que quiera que sea.

> La intención de la tabla de datos es que se asemeje a la plantilla de excel donde tengo que insertar los datos.
>
> El **problema principal es** encontrar el lugar en el array bidimensional donde tengo que insertar cada dato.

El programa lo he escrito en C# por facilidad, pero me vale un **pseudocódigo**, un **algoritmo** para hacerlo, un ejemplo en algún otro lenguaje similar...
Aunque lo ideal sería el pseudocódigo o algoritmo para que cualquiera lo pudiera adaptar a X lenguaje en caso de que fuera necesario.

(EDITO) Este array representa un excel que tengo que rellenar, obteniendo valores de SQL.

```
+—————————————+———————————+
|             |   STOCK   |
+—————————————+———————————+
|  Adidas     |           |
+—————————————+———————————+
| Camisetas   |    52     |  <---- los datos de STOCK se obtienen de SQL 
+—————————————+———————————+
| Pantalones  |    37     |  <---- Lo normal es que vengan vacíos.
+—————————————+———————————+
| Zapatillas  |    15     |
+—————————————+———————————+
|   Puma      |           |
+—————————————+———————————+
| Camisetas   |    55     |
+—————————————+———————————+
| Pantalones  |    73     |
+—————————————+———————————+
|Ropa interior|    21     |
+—————————————+———————————+
|    Nike     |           |
+—————————————+———————————+
|  Zapatillas |    23     |
+—————————————+———————————+
```

Yo hago una consulta a SQL que me devuelve un resultado tipo

```
+—————————+————————————+———————+
|  Marca  |  Producto  | STOCK |
+—————————+————————————+———————+
| Adidas  |  Camiseta  |  52   |
+—————————+————————————+———————+
| Adidas  | Zapatillas |  15   |
+—————————+————————————+———————+
| Puma    | Pantalones |  57   |
+—————————+————————————+———————+
|   ...   |    ...     |  ...  |
+—————————+————————————+———————+
```

Estos tipos de resultados los meto de la siguiente forma.

```
Class Producto(){
    public String marca;
    public String producto;
    public int stock;

    /*pongamos que a parte, aquí hay getters y setters básicos*/

}


Class Principal{

   public static void rellenarLista(){
       /*Establecemos conexion con BBDD lanzamos la consulta y tal*/          

       List<Producto> productos = new List<Producto>();

       While(datareader.Read()){
           Producto p = new Producto();
           p.marca = dr.getString(0);
           p.producto = dr.getString(1);
           p.stock = dr.getInt(2);
           productos.Add(p);
       }
   }
}
```

> Ahora la cosa es, de la `List<Producto> productos` tengo que crear un algoritmo de búsqueda con los siguientes requisitos:
>   - Que ubique cada elemento de Stock en su respectivo lugar del array bidimensional.
>
> - Que sea autosuficiente:
>
>   Si un día yo añado una marca tiene que ser capaz de encontrarla e
>     insertar el dato automáticamente.
> - Que inserte el dato correspondiente a su marca, ya que en la fila los productos tienen el mismo nombre
> - Si existiera un Puma Zapatillas, me lo metería en Nike Zapatillas, por que en la estructura bidimensional, no consta que puma venda zapatillas.
>
> Los problemas que he tenido son:
>
> 1- Posicionamiento de datos.
>   2- Cuando consigo ubicar los datos en sus respectivos lugares o tarda mucho o no consigo ubicarlos correctamente.
>   3- Falta de adaptabilidad, si añades una marca nueva deja de funcionar, el algoritmo no es autosuficiente por lo que no tendrá en cuenta esa marca en un futuro.

Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora.

```
public static void busqueda(){ //se llama busqueda pero perfectamente podría llamarse inserción
  String[,] matriz = new Matriz[num1, num2];
  int fila;      

  Boolean marcaEncontrada;

  for(int lista=0;lista<productos.Count;lista++){
     marcaEncontrada=false;
     for(int i = 0; i<matriz.getLengt(0);i++){ //X
         for(int j = 0; i<getLength(1);j++){   //Y 
              if(matriz[i,j].Contains(productos[lista].getMarca())){
                  marcaEncontrada=true;
              }

              if (excel[i, j].Contains(productos[lista].getProducto() && marcaEncontrada)){
                  fila=i;

              } 


          }
      }
   matriz[fila,1] = productos.getStock();

   }
 }
```

Creo que el código es un poco "chapucilla" pero creo que se entiende para lo que quiero hacer.

Tal y como tengo el código me insertará el código me inserta siempre en el final, es decir, si son unas zapatillas, independientemente de la marca, siempre me los inserta al final, en la parte de **Nike**, si son unos pantalones, siempre me los inserta en la parte de **Puma**.

-La lista la utilizo para poder hacer las comparaciones y insertar todos los datos usando un único bucle.

Comment: ¿Una duda, estas intentando actualizar el Excel (o lo que sea) ?

Comment: Si, bueno, actualizarlo, rellenarlo.... aunque de eso me ocupo después, tengo el excel mapeado en una matriz para tratarlo de forma más fácil

Comment: y no seria mejor recorrer la lista y rellenar el excel directamente en lugar de usar una matriz? Lo digo porque estas manteniendo en memoria el doble de datos.

Comment: Es mejor, si, de eso me ocupare después... el problema principal lo tengo en el algoritmo de búsqueda. Lo del excel está asi por varios motivos ...

Comment: Dado que tu ejemplo utilizas List, por que no miras los métodos que tiene dicho objeto? Normalmente tienen search, add, remove...

Comment: Creo que no acabo de entender el problema de la búsqueda. Supongo que la consulta ya la tienes preparada para ordenar por Marca primero y por tipo de producto después. Por lo que pasarlo a excel solo implicaría leer en orden y escribirlo en ese mismo orden en el excel. Perdona mi ignorancia si no es asi. Un saludo

Comment: @Gerardo en la consulta está organizado así, pero el problema que si en un futuro se añaden nuevas marcas dejaría de funcionar mi aplicación, y mi jefe me pidió que sea autosuficiente.

Comment: @Aritzbn Si tu estas generando el excel completo, al realizar la consulta de nuevo, no deberías tener problemas con las marcas nuevas ni se deberían mezclar los resultados, Simplemente se añadirían en el orden (pongamos alfabético) que tengas en la consulta.

Comment: El excel no lo creo yo, lo descargo de un correo  y el "cliente" es quien lo genera como a el le da la gana, generalmente siempre es el mismo, pero puede que un día quiera cambiar el formato o lo que fuera.

Comment: No queda muy claro cual es tu problema. ¿El excel que muestras al principio aparece con registros que se llaman igual, ese es el problema, o puede ocurrir? En el tercer for pones `getLength(1)` ¿que es?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al final esto es lo que me ha funcionado, teniendo en cuenta el código escrito arriba.

```
public static void busqueda(){ //se llama busqueda pero perfectamente podría llamarse inserción
  String[,] matriz = new Matriz[num1, num2];
  int fila;      

  Boolean marcaEncontrada;
  var marcas = productos.Select(p => p.marca ).Distinct();
 
     for(int lista=0;lista<productos.Count;lista++){
     marcaEncontrada=false;
     for(int i = 0; i<matriz.getLengt(0);i++){ //X
         for(int j = 0; i<getLength(1);j++){   //Y 
              //El IF importante
              if (marcas.Any(m => matriz[i, j].Contains(m)))
              {
                  marcaaEncontrada = compararMarcas(productos[lista].marca, matriz[i, j]);
              }

              if (matriz[i, j].Contains(productos[lista].getProducto() && marcaEncontrada)){
                  fila=i;

              } 
              if(marcaEncontrada && matriz[i,j].Contains(productos.producto)){
              matriz[fila,1] = productos.getStock();
              }
 
          }
      

     }
   }
 }
```

//Metodo compararMarca

```
    public static Boolean compararMarca(String marca, String matriz)
    {
        if (!matriz.Contains(marca))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

El `"IF IMPORTANTE"` lo que hace es comparar si la posición en la matriz es una de las marcas, en caso de serlo entra en el método compararMarcas que devolverá true o false si la marca corresponde con el producto cuyo stock hay que introducir.

De esta forma hacemos que si en un futuro encuentre una marca que no corresponde con el producto a introducir no se vaya a introducir, al mismo tiempo que si se añaden más productos de distintas marcas las tendrá en cuenta ya que obtenemos la marca del producto líneas antes cuando damos valor a  `marcas`.

**Dejo aquí los pasos que sigo esperando que se entienda:**

> -Metemos todos los productos en una lista, con atributos donde se reflejen los atributos producto, stock y marca.
>
> -Metemos todas las marcas en una lista
>
> -Como el excel puede cambiar, hacemos que en cada celda evalue si el contenido de la misma es una marca
>
> -En caso de serlo entraremos a comprobar si la marca coincide con la del producto que estemos insertando en el momento (Que anteriormente hemos obtenido de nuestro origen de datos)
>
> -Si la marca coincide devolvemos true, sino false.
>
> -Con esta variable podemos hacer que, entre en la última condicional, que entrará siempre que la franja sea la de la marca correspondiente o no, en caso de que ambas condiciones se cumplan, entrará en la condición y cambiará el valor de la celda.

**Con esto consigo que:**

> -Si encuentra una marca distinta a la de nuestra lista, no inserte donde no debe.
>
> -Que encuentre correctamente la fila donde debe insertarlo
>
> -Que si en un futuro se añaden más marcas el programa, sin actualizarse,
> siga siendo válido.

Answer (score -1):

yo crearía un diccionario y lo usuaria como indice

y seria el key: marca + producto

y en valor guardia datos de la fila donde se encontró: {RowIndex, CellValue}

ademas añade otro beneficio, será mas rápido

algo así

```
class RowData
{
  public int RowIndex {get; set;}
  public int CellValue {get; set;}
}
```

en busqueda:

```
crear diccionario ubiacionesxls <string, rowData>
crear lista nuevos : new List<Producto>
//recorrrer filas en excel y cargar items existentes

por cada fila in doc.hoja
  si diccionario no tiene (columna_marca + column_producto)
    agregar ubiacionesxls.add(column_marca + column_producto, new RowData(){ doc.hoja.row, numero_de_celda_valor })
terminar por

//después de cargar el diccionario
//recuperamos lo ultimo en stock
dataReader = repository.GetData(parametros...)

mientras dataReader.read
   var itemkey = datareader.get["column_marca"] + datareader.get["column_pructo"]
   si (ubiacionesxls.containskey(item))
   {
        //actualizamos existentes
        var rowData = ubiacionesxls[item]
        //posicionar en fila celda
        doc.hoja.row = rowData.Row
        doc.hoja.cell = rowData.CellValue
        doc.hoja.SetValue(dataReader.get["column_value"]);
   }
   sino 
   {
       //guardamos el nuevo item para agregar al final del excel
       nuevos.add(new Producto{ Marca = dataReader.get["column_marca"] }, 
       Producto = dataReader.get["column_marca"],
       Stock = dataReader.get["column_value"])
   }
termina mientras
```

//cargamos los nuevos al final de la hoja de excel

```
var lastRow = doc.hoja.lastindex;

por cada p in nuevos
{
  doc.hoja.row = lastRow + 1
  doc.hoja.cell = marca_column_index
  doc.hoja.SetValue(dataReader.get["column_marca"]); 

  doc.hoja.cell = marca_column_index
  doc.hoja.SetValue(dataReader.get["column_producto"]);

  doc.hoja.cell = marca_column_index
  doc.hoja.SetValue(dataReader.get["column_stock"]); 
  lastRow++
}
```

Comment: Esto no es lo que busco. El algoritmo debe encontrar la fila y columna donde insertar los datos, en tu algoritmo no veo donde obtienes tanto la fila como la columna. :$